# Getting products name into database

Tags: php

I've got a list of products-name inside a txt file. However, the file is huge (4,8GB++) so yes, it's a lot of words. Along with the product-name, i would like to add some additional information like a md5 hash, time, and random ID.

What would be the best solution for doing this? Creating a PHP script reading line by line, seems to take forever.

Any good suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if you were planning to use the random ID for a product code but if you are I wound't as you might get a clash.

Comment: Take your time. 4 GB files will take a lot of time to iterate over **line-by-line**.

Comment: i will use a random code, along with date, time information etc. So there should not be a crash. i can also combie it with the length of the word or hash it.

Comment: Load data to db MySQL/PostgreSQL will take ~40 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use php to read a text file and pass it to a database

```
$string = file_get_contents("YOURTEXTFILE", "r");
$myFile = "PATH/TO/YOUR/TEXTFILE";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("Could not open: " . mysql_error());
fwrite($fh, $string);
fclose($fh);

$sql = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password");
if (!$sql) {
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("YOURDB");
$result = mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE '$myFile'" .
                      " INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'");
if (!$result) {
    die("Could not load. " . mysql_error());
```

}

and the result will be like this

```
+--------+-------------+------------+
|     ID | Name        | time       |
+--------+-------------+------------+
|    145 | line1       | 23:59      |
|    234 | line2       | 00:00      |
+--------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: so what if i wanted to hash the word, along with an ID? to create an uniq hash

Comment: ....[`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) if false === [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)?

Answer (score 0):

I've put more thought into your problem, I've used this solution before, but I'm not sure if it'll work for you due to the size of your file. I'll leave it here for now in case it's useful for someone else.

Assuming your product.txt file only has productIDs and nothing else you could:

1. Change each line to be surrounded by parenthesis (this can be achieved by doing a find/replace of NEWLINE (usually **\n**) for **),\n(** )
2. Then place a query at the top; and make sure the end of the file closes a valid query
3. Import with mysql like any mysqldump

Basically change

```
PID1
PID2
```

to

```
(PID1),
(PID2),
```

and then with some simple editing make the file read

```
INSERT INTO dTable(ColName) VALUES
(PID1),
(PID2);
```

and finally import

```
mysql -uUser -p DATABASE < filename.sql
```

It's a rudimentary method, but should work without too much hassle. Adding the rest of the data you want to it will be simpler to do in SQL afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql and the file is CSV type, then you can use `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

You don't need PHP at all if you have a well formed CSV.

Let me know if that is the case and I can add more detail.